# Using Zend Service Amazon S3 after installation with composer - Zend Framework 2.3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2, composer-php

I just installed Zend Service Amazon 2.0.3 with composer.

[Amazon Packagist here](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendservice-amazon)

Composers worked fine and the S3's dir is:

```
vendor:
------>zendframework:
------------->zendservice-amazon:
---------------------------->library:
---------------------------------->ZendService:
---------------------------------------------->Amazon:
------------------------------------------------------>S3:
```

within autoload_namespaces.php file:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
    'ZendService\\Amazon\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendservice-amazon/library'),
    'ZendRest' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendrest/library'),
);
```

I don't understand to use S3 class. I tried to use:

```
$s3 = new ZendService\Amazon\S3($k1, $k2);
```

or

```
use ZendService\Amazon;
$s3 = new ZendService\Amazon\S3($k1, $k2);
```

or

```
use ZendService\Amazon\S3;
$s3 = new Amazon\S3($k1, $k2);
```

or

```
use ZendService\Amazon\S3;
$s3 = new S3($k1, $k2);
```

but the errors are like this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZendService\Amazon\S3' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\my-site\module\Upload\src\Upload\Controller\UploadController.php on line 38
```

how can I use S3 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it

```
$s3 = new \ZendService\Amazon\S3\S3($AccKey, $SecrKey);
```

but I don't doing anything! example,

```
$s3->createBucket('my-bucket-name-is-secret', 'eu-central-1');
```

apparently doesn't appear any error, but if I check in my s3's console, there isn't any bucket.